# Adding value to an hash in perl

Tags: perl

I am writing a perl script.
I want to assign two variables as value to an hash as shown below.

```
$O_seq_err{$bill.$send}=($PACK_INDEX_VAL $val);
```

I need a space between the variables.
Can I assign it like this. Will this work?

Comment: "Will this work?" What happened when you tried it? I mean, I can't see why you wouldn't just try it rather asking here.

Answer (score 3):

No.

If you want "a space between two variables" then presumably what you mean is "A string consisting of the value of the first variable, then a space, then the value of the second variable".

> ```
> ($PACK_INDEX_VAL $val)
> ```

… is a syntax error.

You want:

```
"$PACK_INDEX_VAL $val"
```

or

```
$PACK_INDEX_VAL . " " . $val
```

or

```
sprintf("%s %s", $PACK_INDEX_VAL, $val)
```

or

```
join " ", $PACK_INDEX_VAL, $val
```

Comment: Or perhaps put the two variables into an array: `[ $PACK_INDEX_VAL, $val ]`